# How do I create an array of date intervals from an array of dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, date-fns

From an array:

```
["01/01/2015", "02/01/2015", "03/01/2015", "05/01/2015", "06/01/2015"];
```

to

```
[{start_date: "01/01/2015", end_date: "03/01/2015"}, { start_date: "05/05/2015", end_date: "06/01/2015 }];
```

Is there a library available for this type of functions?

I would like to convert the first array  dates to an array of objects that represent time intervals.

PS: date format in the question is dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: What did you try? Is there a logic, why is index-0 the start of the first one, but index-1 the start of the second one?

Comment: The reduce method could be an option, but how would you know which one is the start and end date for each item?

Comment: And where did `"02/01/2015"` go?

Comment: The map method would be an option, but as Franco said it seems you are randomly selecting start and end dates. 2/01/2015 wasnt used in your example. Best bet for accurate help is to provide a working snippet of what you have tried so we can guide you.

Comment: The min is the start and the max is the end in the example we have 2 intervals because 01-01, 02-01 and 03-01 are consecutive they can form this interval 01-01 to 03-01 and the second one is 05-01 to 06-01

Comment: The date format in the question is dd-MM-yyyy the month is jan

Comment: @hichemchouaibi—your last two comments should be in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const strings = ["01/01/2015", "02/01/2015", "03/01/2015", "05/01/2015", "06/01/2015"];

const dates = strings.map(str => ({
  date: new Date(str.split(/\//g).reverse().join('-') + 'T00:00:00Z'),
  string: str
}))

let current = { start_date: dates[0].string }

const intervals = [current]

for (let i = 1; i < dates.length; i += 1) {
  const diff = (dates[i].date - dates[i - 1].date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
  if (diff === 1) {
    current.end_date = dates[i].string
  } else {
    current = { start_date: dates[i].string }
    intervals.push(current)
  }
}

console.log(intervals)
```

Comment: This was the path i thought as well. however it assumes the arr will always be in chronological order. may want to add a sort first to the array

Comment: @PeterThoeny no, op has specified that it's DD/mm/yyyy

Comment: In Safari, this returns an array of objects `{from: null}`. The string "2015-01-05Z" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari treats it as an invalid attempt at YYYY-MM-DD. BTW, that format is parsed as UTC anyway so the Z is redundant and demonstrably harmful. ISO 8601 date–only strings do not have a timezone, they're treated as local (ECMAScript treating them as UTC is an exception).

Comment: @RobG Should work in safari now (although I'm not proud of it, this browser should die). Also, without the `Z` the dates are converted to my local time zone which doesn't seem to be correct, but I'm not a date expert and you can be right

Comment: @Konrad—re "*without the Z the dates are converted to my local time zone*". If correct, it's a bug. Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera all conform to ECMA-262 (e.g. `new Date('2023-01-01').toISOString()` produces "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" regardless of system settings).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to compare timestamps with the same format. Initialise ranges with the "start_date" value, then when the dates are no longer contiguous, set the "end_date" value and initialise another range with "start_date".

The last element in the array is always the final "end_date".

The following also deals with single dates, setting it to "end_date" and "start_date". The source array should be sorted from oldest to newest date.

```js
// Parse timestamp in dd/mm/yyyy format
function parseDMY(s) {
  let [D, M, Y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Y, M-1, D);
}

// Format a Date as dd/mm/yyyy
function formatDMY(date = new Date()) {
  let z = n => (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
  return `${z(date.getDate())}/${z(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}

// Return a new Date that is date + n days
function addDays(date = new Date(), n = 1) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + Number(n));
}

let dates = [
  // 3 days contiguous in month
  // start_date: 01/91/2015, end_date: 03/01/2015
  "01/01/2015", "02/01/2015", "03/01/2015",
  
  // 2 days contiguous in month
  // start_date: 05/01/2015, end_date: 06/01/2015,
  "05/01/2015", "06/01/2015",
  
  // Single day
  // start_date: 09/01/2015, end_date: 09/01/2015
  "09/01/2015",

  // 3 days contiguous over month end
  // start_date: 30/01/2018, end_date: 01/02/2018
  "30/01/2018", "31/01/2018", "01/02/2018",
  
  // 3 days contiguous over year end
  // start_date: 30/12/2018, end_date: 01/01/2019
  "30/12/2018", "31/12/2018", "01/01/2019", "02/01/2019"
  
  ];

// Create ranges
let ranges = dates.reduce((acc, d, i, arr) => {
  let range = acc[acc.length - 1];
  
  // Initialise if range has no "start_date"
  if (!range.start_date) {
    range.start_date = d;
    
  // If date not contiguous, set range "end_date" and initialise
  // new range with "start_date"
  } else if (formatDMY(addDays(parseDMY(range.start_date), i - arr.indexOf(range.start_date))) != d) {
    range.end_date = arr[i - 1];
    acc.push({start_date: d});
  } 
  
  // Set last element in source array as final "end_date"
  if (i == arr.length - 1) {
    acc[acc.length - 1].end_date = d;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, [Object.create(null)])

console.log(ranges)
```